# How to access form element xyz[] in Javascript?

Tags: php, javascript

I have code that will automatically add a new similar row defined in form by clicking add   button.

```
<html>
<body>
<form>
<input type="text" name="quantity[]" class="input_text" id="pro"/> 
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Now I want to access different values of `quantity[]` in javascript function .

How to access this different values of `quantity[]` in javascript using it's ID or Name Attribute.

```
  <script>
  function abc() {
      var id = document.getElementById("pro").value;
  }
  </script>
```

Comment: If all your items use the same ID, that renders IDs unusable.

Comment: IDs should be unique, that's the point - they identify an element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this.

html:

```
<form>

    <input name="p_id[]" value="0"/>
    <input name="p_id[]" value="1"/>
    <input name="p_id[]" value="2"/>

</form>
```

javascript:

```
var p_ids = document.forms[0].elements["p_id[]"];
alert(p_ids.length);
for (var i = 0, len = p_ids.length; i < len; i++) {
  alert(p_ids[i].value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The way to do that with plain JavaScript is to get all the elements with an specific name, as following:

```
var fields = document.getElementsByName('quantity[]');
```

Should you want to access an specific value, you could do that as well:

```
console.log(fields[0].value); // foo
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A4tGq/1/) with a code sample.

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<form name="order">
    <input type="text" name="quantity[]" class="input_text" /> 
    <input type="text" name="quantity[]" class="input_text" /> 
    <input type="text" name="quantity[]" class="input_text" /> 
</form>
```

JS:

```
var elements = document.forms['order'].elements['quantity[]'];
console.log(elements[1].value); // outputs the value of the 2nd element.
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/NDbwt/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[name=quantity]').each(function(){
    alert($(this).val())
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First: id must be unique on page. Otherwise document.getElementById will always return first spotted element with requested id.

In your case, you may do next:

```
var id = document.getElementsByName("quantity[]")[0].value;
```

But more safely (I'm not sure if order of items in returned array will always be the same as order in which elements are added) would be to generate ids like pro_0, pro_1, pro_2 etc

Answer (score 0):

You're probably confused by the fact that PHP reads form fields as arrays when you use square brackets on their name. That's only a PHP trick—for JavaScript, `[]` does not have any special meaning and you can read the items in the usual way:

```
var values = [];
var fields = document.getElementsByName("quantity[]");
for (var i = 0, len = fields.length; i < len; i++) {
    values.push(fields[i].value);
}
alert("Values:\n" + values.join("\n"));
```

See it [in action](http://jsfiddle.net/gSVJB/).